# Sqlite select query using result value from another select query from another table

Tags: sqlite, select

I have checked the similar answer but didn't find what i am looking for.

I have a table from where I get a value like below:

```
SELECT value1 from table1;
b3
```

I need to use this result for my next query:

```
SELECT b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,(SELECT value from table1) from table2;
15.26|13.14|11.08|9.05|7.05|b3
15.31|13.2|11.14|9.11|7.12|b3
15.37|13.26|11.2|9.18|7.18|b3
15.43|13.32|11.26|9.24|7.25|b3
```

the problem is that the SELECT statement is returning b3 instead of b3 values as per the following result (last column is return of b2 from the select)

```
SELECT b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,(SELECT value from table1) from table2;
15.26|13.14|11.08|9.05|7.05|11.08
15.31|13.2|11.14|9.11|7.12|11.14
15.37|13.26|11.2|9.18|7.18|11.2
15.43|13.32|11.26|9.24|7.25|11.26
```

any idea how to solve this? many thanks

Comment: Show your data in both tables and your expected results. Its unclear atm

Comment: The result `b3` that you see is the value of the column `value1`, but `b1,b2,b3` are the names of the columns with values `100,200,13.23`. These are 2 different things.

Comment: sorry, my bad, I have badly formatted my question, i have added some clarifications. pls let me know if this is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want a CASE expression:

```
SELECT b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,
  CASE (SELECT value from table1) 
    WHEN 'b1' THEN b1
    WHEN 'b2' THEN b2
    WHEN 'b3' THEN b3
    WHEN 'b4' THEN b4
    WHEN 'b5' THEN b5
  END result  
FROM table2
```

but this will work only if:

```
SELECT value from table1
```

returns only 1 row. 
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h1VZFtduxcCrFKirCMS8Gv/1).
Results:

```
| b1    | b2    | b3    | b4   | b5   | result |
| ----- | ----- | ----- | ---- | ---- | ------ |
| 15.26 | 13.14 | 11.08 | 9.05 | 7.05 | 11.08  |
| 15.31 | 13.2  | 11.14 | 9.11 | 7.12 | 11.14  |
| 15.37 | 13.26 | 11.2  | 9.18 | 7.18 | 11.2   |
| 15.43 | 13.32 | 11.26 | 9.24 | 7.25 | 11.26  |
```

Comment: this is working as expected, many thanks for your help. is it possible to not specify all the columns? b1-b5. how can it be done in an efficient way if we have 100 columns?

Comment: There is no direct link between a string like `'b3'` with a column's name like `b3`, so any solution would have to enumerate all the columns. This is because of the design of Table2.